# Is there any lock that can prevent the content of a page from being modified? How does ksm ensure this before merging two identical pages?

Tags: linux-kernel, locking

I'm currently reading KSM(kernel same page merging) code.
I have seen that several locks are used in that code:
down_read/upread mmap_sem, lock_page() and page table lock (eg: pte_offset_map_lock).

As far as I know,
mmap_sem: mm lock, used to protect vma
page lock: used to lock the struct page (But I can modify the content of a page without changing the page descriptor)
page table lock: lock the pte

None of them can prevent the page content from changing.

So is there any lock can achieve this? How ksm ensure that the page content is not changed right before merging two identical pages? By write protecting these pages? In that case, it should write-protect the pages as soon as the contents of the two pages are found identical, but in the code this seems not the case.

Comment: KSM should only be run on COW pages.

Answer (score 0):

pte_wrprotect before merging and after which virtual page mapped at  COW.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But isn't it too late to write protect the pte just before merging? Shouldn't it be done right before comparing the content of the pages? Since the page content might change after you find two pages are identical, if you write protect just before merging, you might write-protect two pages and merge them that you thought are identical but actually not.

Comment: @user16430563 If you look at `try_to_merge_one_page` you can see that after write protecting the page (`write_protect_page()`), it compares the contents of the two pages (`pages_identical()`) before replacing a page in the VMA (`replace_page()`).

Comment: Yes, agree with @IanAbbott. Please look at function try_to_merge_one_page which protect PTE, Check Identical  and then replace